# How to compare two dataframes, and add the rows and columns which one of the two doesn`t have

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have a small dataframe with fewer rows and columns than a bigger dataframe.
How can I add the rows and columns which are in the bigger dataframe, and populate them with zero? Basically I want to add the cells in red in the picture below:

[image]

A toy example is below. I have tried with pandas.concat, but I end up with all the values from the bigger dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_big = pd.DataFrame(index=["a","b","c","d"])
df_big["x"] = np.arange(4)
df_big["y"] = df_big.x * 2
df_big["z"] = df_big.x * 3

df_small=pd.DataFrame(index=["a","b"])
df_small["x"]=[8,10]
df_small["y"]=[30,40]

out = pd.concat( [df_big, df_small] , axis=0)
```

Comment: Why do you need `df_big` if you aren't using any values from it on **desired output**?

Comment: My dataframes are the results of groupby and crosstabs. I still need to show every category, even if not present in a particular subset (therefore dataframe) of my data. E.g. imagine the country of Ruritania has no inhabitants older than 70; I'd still need to show the category "70+" in my table, because I am comparing Ruritania with other countries that do have that category. Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for [`DataFrame.align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html):

```
_, out = df_big.align(df_small, fill_value=0)
out

    x   y  z
a   8  30  0
b  10  40  0
c   0   0  0
d   0   0  0
```

---

You can also use [`DataFrame.reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) on `df_small`:

```
df_small.reindex_like(df_big).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

    x   y  z
a   8  30  0
b  10  40  0
c   0   0  0
d   0   0  0
```

Comment: based on the value of axis, align() can be sued to add missing rows, missing columns, or both. That's great - thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous yep , it is :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `mul` with `notnull`

```
df_small.mul(df_big.notnull(),fill_value=0).astype(int)
Out[275]: 
    x   y  z
a   8  30  0
b  10  40  0
c   0   0  0
d   0   0  0
#df_small.mul(df_big.astype(bool),fill_value=0).astype(int) # change to astype will achieve the same
```

Comment: I am surprised that mul() works even when y is a column of strings

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can also use [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update), i.e.:

```
df_big[:] = 0
df_big.update(df_small, join='left', overwrite=True)
```

---

```
      x     y  z
a   8.0  30.0  0
b  10.0  40.0  0
c   0.0   0.0  0
d   0.0   0.0  0
```